# How to Serialize Map<String,String> to an Array of Key:Values

Tags: java, json, jackson

How do you serialize a map of keys-value pairs such that that the resulting JSON has the form:

```
["key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "keyN":"valueN"]
```

The default way that a Map is serialized is in the form:

```
{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "keyN":"valueN"}
```

The custom serializer that I tried to make seems to want to put them in separate objects as when I take the comments out of the below snippet

```
public class MapToArraySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map<String,String>>
{
    @Override
    public void serialize(Map<String,String> additionalData, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException
    {
        generator.writeStartArray();
        for (String key : additionalData.keySet()) {
            //generator.writeStartObject();
            generator.writeObjectField(key, additionalData.get(key));
            //generator.writeEndObject();
        }
        generator.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

I get the following:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator._reportError(JsonGenerator.java:1886)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.writeFieldName(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:126)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.writeObjectField(JsonGenerator.java:1651)
```

Comment: Your resulting JSON is not really a valid list. Do you actually mean to make a list of objects, ie.`[{"key1":"value1"}, {"key2":"value2"}, {"keyN":"valueN"}]`?

Comment: Are you trying to write an array or a map? If you are writing a Map, I suspect `writeStartArray` is not what you want.

Comment: @Henrik that makes sense given the JsonGenerationException. Is there a way to force it even though it is not valid?

Comment: @BrianHarman: I suspect that one of Jackson's primary use cases is to prevent you from doing it. :) If you really are serious about including it, you could look into creating the string yourself and using the `@JsonRawValue` annotation to have Jackson turn off validation before serializing.

Comment: @Henrik I'll take a look at `@JsonRawValue`.  It's the system I am writing to so I don't really have a choice.

Comment: your question is wrong from the very beginning... ["key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "keyN":"valueN"] is not a valid JSON array. you either wrap each key-value pair as an object and place them all in an array, or stick to a single object from the first place. as the name sais it, writeObjectField is for writing into object not into arrays...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Henrik pointed out, this is not valid but I was able to accomplish this by using the `@JsonRawValue` annotation:

```
@JsonRawValue
public String getAdditionalData()
{
    String json = "[";
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(additionalData.keySet());
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        String key = keys.get(i);
        json = json + "\"" + key + "\":\"" + additionalData.get(key) + "\"";
        if (i + 1 < keys.size()) {
            json = json + ",";
        }
    }
    return json + "]";
}
```

Comment: Ewww, but happy that you managed to solve it, although I do feel slightly dirty now. ;)

Comment: definitely not a good solution long term. This isn't even escaping the data.